# Emgu CV: HaarCascade.Detect respects ROI?

Tags: emgucv

I looked in the documentation of Emgu CV but didn't find anything relevant. I just want to make sure: does HaarCascade.Detect respect the ROI, so that the detection is only performed in the subarea designated by the ROI?

```
Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame;

grayFrame.ROI = eyesROI;
HaarCascade.Detect(grayFrame);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **Yes** the haar cascade will only use the data within the ROI of you frame data. I take it your going to detect the face and then use its position to set the ROI and look for the eyes. This should work nicely if you hit difficulties simply increase the ROI slightly until the cascade starts working.

Cheers

Chris